# "Manin's theorem" reference, coding theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, asymptotics, information-theory, coding-theory

**Question:**

In the book [1], a theorem called "Manin's Theorem" is stated on page 19

"There exists a continuous decreasing function $\alpha_q : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that

- $\alpha_q$ is strictly decreasing on $[ 0,\frac{q-1}{q}]$,
- $\alpha_q(0) = 1$,
- if $\frac{q-1}{q} \leq x \leq 1$, then $\alpha_q(x)=0$,
- $\Sigma_q = \lbrace (\delta,R) \in [0,1]^2 \mid 0 \leq R \leq \alpha_q(\delta) \rbrace$."

The citation for this is given as [2], but on Google Scholar this is some random book from 1903. It's also the case that "Manin's theorem" isn't a very specific name, considering the amount of varied work done by Manin. I'm looking for a place to find [2] online, or another alternate reference to find this theorem and its proof.

**References**:

[1] Joyner, David, and Jon-Lark Kim. Selected unsolved problems in coding theory. Springer Science & Business Media, 2011.

[2] Shokranian, Salahoddin, and Mohammad Amin Shokrollahi. Coding theory and bilinear complexity. Vol. 21., Juelich, International Office of the Forschungszentrum Juelich, 1993.

Comment: Just for completeness, here's a more thorough reference for [2]: https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/99659 . I found this by clicking the "All 2 versions" link at the bottom of this [scholar page](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=ho_asq8AAAAJ&cstart=100&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=ho_asq8AAAAJ:gVv57TyPmFsC), which is a useful trick for chasing down proper references when Scholar's indexing screws up.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks a bunch, I just edited my post so that it's a bit more complete :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to the question as stated literally:

Citation 2 is found [here](https://juser.fz-juelich.de/record/892571/files/Scientific_Series_21.pdf?version=1) and the paper of Manin is [here](https://gkorpal.github.io/files/Manin1981.pdf), see in particular Theorem 3 on p. 716.
Still, I don't see the exact correlation to what the authors Joyner and Kim write in their book.

Comment: I think a literal answer to the question is good enough for me -- even if it's not as satisfying mathematically, at least it gives reading to dig into a bit more :D and that can always be pretty fun, imo.

Answer (score 4):

My impression is that the intention of the authors is to introduce the function $\alpha_q$ and to state a few of its properties. But the way they do it ("there exists ... such that") looks a bit clumsy to me. Why not first give the common definition of $\alpha_q$ and then state its properties.

The function $\alpha_q(\delta)$ is commonly defined as the best possible asymptotic information rate of a $q$-nary block code of asymptotic relative distance $\delta$.

See for example Section 2.10 in the book [Fundamentals of Error-Correcting codes](https://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511807077) by W. Cary Huffman & Vera Pless, 2003.
A lot of other textbooks written for a mathematical audience should do, too.

There are lower and upper bounds known for the function $\alpha_q$, but the exact values are unknown (in the open interval $(0,1 - \frac{1}{q})$). This is an important open problem in coding theory, most prominently in the binary case $q = 2$.

Let me remark that the term "Manin's theorem" is new to me.
A few remarks on your four listed points:

- **EDIT**: Actually, I'm not sure about the property **strictly** decreasing on $[0,1-\frac{1}{q}]$. Has this really been shown? Where? Does anyone have a reference?
- The asympotic rate of the full Hamming space gives $\alpha_q(0) = 1$.
- This follows from the asymptotic Plotkin bound and the specific value $\alpha_q(1 - \frac{1}{q}) = 0$ follows from the asymptotic Elias-Bassalygo bound (or the knowledge that $\alpha_q$ is continuous).
- I guess, this is the common definition of $\alpha_q$ (I don't know what $\Sigma_q$ is).

Comment: I know, right? Both the continuity and strictly decreasing nature of $\alpha_q$ were unexpected to me. What got me even more curious was that on the following page, Joyner and Kim state nothing is known about the convexity or differentiability of $\alpha_q$, while I'm over here still surprised about continuity and strict decreasing!

Comment: Oh also, even though I knew the basic coding theory information you provided in your answer, I appreciate you writing it out, especially for other MathSE users -- I'll try to be better about giving background in future questions, myself.

Comment: @AidanW.Murphy Continuity has been shown by m. Aaltonen, "Notes on the asymptotic behavior of the information rate of block codes", IEEE Trans. Inf. Theory 30 (1984), 84-85. But I'm still wondering where **strictly** decreasing has been shown, maybe this is a hoax?? Joyner and Kim cite [2] Shokranian and Shokrollahi, I guess the citation goes to their Theorem (1.17). However, in that source I don't see anything about **strict** monotonicity.